# На чём писать сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Я хочу создать сайт, но, как бы банально не звучало, не знаю на чём и как. Что я хочу на нём реализовать: голосовалочки за посты, комменты; авторизацию через соц. сети, mail ну и такое прочее. Естественно, я начал гуглить, и просто таки погряз в информации: meteor.js, derby, django, ruby on rails, flask и еще очень-очень много подобных. О своих навыках: могу html/css, могу java (более-менее). Читал, что нужно js, думаю, со знаниями джавa выучить js до определённого уровня не составит особых проблем.

Comment: Да собсна на чем угодно - чятики и голосовалочки каких-то особо специфических средств не требуют.

Comment: если НЕ ХОТИТЕ долго мучиться - возьмите какую-то цмс, там этих модулей навалом. Если ХОТИТЕ долго мучиться - начинайте штудировать ЯП-ы.

Comment: @mountpoint, почему-то всегда выходит наоборот: если ХОЧЕШЬ долго мучаться, то можно взять CMS, а если ХОЧЕШЬ легко и ненапряжно сделать сайт под свои нужды и не перекапывать кучу гавнокода, то используй framework

Comment: @111xbot111, раз пишете на Java, так попробуйте сделать все на ней  (клиентская часть, например, smartgwt, а серверная, скажем, сервлеты в tomcat).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зря вы так про js, java это совсем другой язык и js с нуля это не так просто с учётом того, как быстро сейчас развивается web.

По поводу веб-разработки тут всё просто двигайтесь в сторону сочетания:

1. Серверный framework
2. Frontend-framework или просто набор библиотек и стилей

Серверный framework:

- на php - Symfony2, Yii2, Lavarel
- на Rubi on rails - названия не знаю, но точно есть
- на Js - node.js

Frontend framework:

Я бы рекомендовал Twitter Bootstrap, он очень хорошо задокументирован и популярен. А можно и вообще не использовать никаких, прикрутить нужные плагины и библотеки на JS, написать стили, рекомендую использовать LESS (SASS), вот и весь frontend.

Comment: @MasterAlex, я ни в коем случае не говорю плохо о js, просто имею в виду, что я не нулевой и знаю основы типа наследования, инкапсулирования. А подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из языков к java ближайший? Или простейший в освоении?

Еще вопрос: не могли бы Вы посоветовать какие-нибудь туториалы (желательно русскоязычные, но и англоязычные тоже)? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: > js с нуля это не так просто с учётом того, как быстро сейчас развивается web.

Эм. Как это связано?

> на Rubi on rails - названия не знаю, но точно есть

rails сам по себе фреймворк, просто на рубях он затмил все остальные, поэтому когда говорят "рельсы" и "руби", имеют в виду практически одно и то же.

Answer (score 3):

Если  есть желание годик-два покопаться в Web'е, тогда можно смело выбирать между PHP и ASP.NET для серверной части, и jQuery для клиентской.
Иначе, ставить любой более популярный движок и пичкать его плагинами

Comment: @Ni55aN, спасибо за ответ. Я не очень хочу использовать cms, не знаю даже почему так. Наверное, хочется ручками всё это сделать, чтоб кухню изнутри понимать. А php - столько флеймов вокруг него, что до сих пор не понимаю,то ли годная штука, то ли все-таки уже нинужон.

Answer (score 2):

Пиши на php,
но сначала почитай про ООП (не то, как он работает (синтаксис классов), а про то, как его использовать и как проектировать объектные модели).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в том же ютубе много вариантов "создай сайт с нуля". По принципу делай, как я, можно спародировать себе простенькие странички. Если что-то серьезное, то тут несколько сложнее:

1. ХТМЛ нужен для разметки, плохой ХТМЛ - плохая настройка.
2. КСС - красивости, плохой КСС - нестабильное отображение (некрасивое минимум).
3. Яваскрипт - откликаемость и динамичность сайта, плохой скрипт - и сайт похож на постер в дешевом журнале.
4. ПХП - работа с сервером, плохой пхп - сайт работает только с флэшки. ))

Зы. Вообще есть сайты-конструкторы с халявным хостингом, в зависимости от назначения твоего сайта может имеет смысл рассмотреть такой вариант. По мне сырой сайт по образу и подобию сделанный с красивым доменом мало чем отличается от стандартизированного c громостким доменом.